# Safari animation not working

Tags: css, safari

i have the following CSS rule

```
*.highlight {
            @-webkit-keyframes blink {
                0% {
                    outline: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }

                50% {
                    outline: 5px solid red;
                }

                100% {
                    outline: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);    
                }
            }

            @keyframes blink {
                0% {
                    outline: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }

                50% {
                    outline: 5px solid red;
                }

                100% {
                    outline: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);    
                }
            }

            animation: blink normal 1.5s infinite ease-in-out;

            -webkit-animation-name: blink;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

which works fine in all browsers, except safari. I have googled and googled and all the similar answers ive found revolve around transforms, which I am not using (here at least) can anyone help?

Comment: something that works? If you're answer worked I would mark it as such. unfortunately it nothing changes

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Joseph Silber previous answer in a previous answer I managed to get it working simply by changing the outline colour not the entire outline (see below).

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        outline-color: transparent;
    }

    50% {
        outline-color: red;
    }

    100% {
        outline-color: transparent; 
    }
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        outline-color: transparent;
    }

    50% {
        outline-color: red;
    }

    100% {
        outline-color: transparent; 
    }
}

*.highlight {
    animation: blink normal 1.5s infinite ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    outline: 5px solid red;

    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```